# VueJS View is not refreshing when I change the router paramId

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have the following router that accepts a param ID

```
{   
   path: '/Filters/Edit/:id',
   name: 'Manager.FilterEditor',
   component: FilterEditor
},
```

When I try to navigate from one filter to another using `router.push`, the view remains the same.

`router.push({ name: 'Manager.FilterEditor', params: { id: newfilter.id } });`

The URL updates to the new ID, but the models remain the same.

Answer (score 8):

You have to add a `key` attribute at the `router-view` in the master view.

`<router-view :key="$route.path" />`

The key will help VueJS to notice the change and trigger the model bounding and the view redraw.

Comment: You might not always want to re-render the entire view when a parameter is changed. Changing a parameter might only be responsible for changing one portion of a view and thus you wouldn't want the overhead of re-rendering the entire view unless absolutely necessary. This solution might be a good fit for some scenarios, just worth thinking about if it's exactly what you need.

Comment: @EricUldall Is there any other solution? Please note that the parameter is at the url.

Comment: You can place a :key only on components that need to be re-rendered. It's excessive putting it on the router-view because that means every route will be re-rendered anytime the url changes...this kind of loses a lot of the power of reactive applications. Try to build components that encapsulate the parts of your application well enough to change them when needed and reduce overhead and rendering lag.